# Sliders library

Tags: javascript, api

I have completed working on my own pure JavaScript Slider library and would like to get some input from other developers. I would like to know how you would improve the code in any way.

```
( function( window, undefined ) {

function Slider(el, opts) {

/**************
 GLOBAL VARS
***************/

var that = this;

//configurables        
var opts = opts || {},
    el = el,
    minvalue = opts.minvalue || 0,
    maxvalue = opts.maxvalue || 10,
    step = opts.step || 1,
    change = opts.change || null; 

//create elements and variables
var dragging = false, //if dragger handle is being dragged
    draggerStartPos, //the starting position (x coordinate) of dragger 
    lineWidth, 
    currentValue = 0,   
    range = (maxvalue - minvalue) / step, //draggable positions
    fraction, //a draggable position in pxs
    clientX, 
    clientY, 

    holder = document.createElement("div"),
    line = document.createElement("div"),
    dragger = document.createElement("div");

//the custom event that will be created  
var event; 

/**************
 PRIVATE SCOPE
***************/

/* 
 * Check if it's a touch device
 */ 
var _isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return /BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return /IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (_isMobile.Android() || _isMobile.BlackBerry() || _isMobile.iOS() || _isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

/*
 * Main initialisation function 
 */
var _init = function(){
  //construct interface     
  holder.setAttribute("class", "slider-holder");
  line.setAttribute("class", "slider-line");      
  dragger.setAttribute("class", "slider-dragger");

  line.appendChild(dragger);
  holder.appendChild(line);
  el.appendChild(holder); 

  lineWidth = line.offsetWidth - dragger.offsetWidth; 
  fraction = lineWidth / range; 

  if(_isMobile.any()) {
    //handling touch events
    dragger.addEventListener("touchstart", _dragStart, false);
  } else {
    //bind event handlers 
    dragger.onmousedown = _dragStart;  
  } 

  _initChangeEvent();
}

/*
 * Create a custom change event for slider  
 */
var _initChangeEvent = function(){
  //custom event creation 
  if (document.createEvent) {
    event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent("change", true, true);
  } else {
    event = document.createEventObject();
    event.eventType = "change";
  }
  event.eventName = "change";
}

/*
 * Dispatches the event 
 */
var _fireChangeEvent = function(){
  if (document.createEvent) {
    el.dispatchEvent(event);
  } else {
    el.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
  }
}

/*
 * Function called when onmousedown/touchstart event is fired   
 * @param {Object} e Event object   
 */
var _dragStart = function(e){
  if(!e){ e = window.event; }
  e.preventDefault();

  //flag to indicate we have strated dragging
  dragging = true;

  if(_isMobile.any()){
    dragger.addEventListener("touchmove", _dragMove, false);
    dragger.addEventListener("touchend", _dragStop, false);
  } else {
    dragger.onmousemove = _dragMove; 
    dragger.onmouseup = _dragStop; 

    window.onmousemove = _dragMove;
    window.onmouseup = _dragStop;
  }

  if(e.changedTouches !== undefined){
    clientX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    clientY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY; 
  } else {
    clientX = e.clientX; 
    clientY = e.clientY; 
  }

  //work out the start position of the dragger minus the x coordinate of where the user clicked
  draggerStartPos = (clientX - dragger.offsetLeft) - (holder.offsetLeft + line.offsetLeft); 
}

/*
 * Function called when onmousemove/touchmove event is fired
 * @param {Object} e Event object      
 */
var _dragMove = function(e){
  if(!e){ e = window.event; }
  e.preventDefault();

  if(dragging === true) {
    //prevent cursor to switching to default one  
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';

    if(e.changedTouches !== undefined){
      clientX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
      clientY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY; 
    } else {
      clientX = e.clientX; 
      clientY = e.clientY; 
    }

    //work out new position of dragger
    var newPos = (clientX - draggerStartPos) - (holder.offsetLeft + line.offsetLeft);

    var prevDraggerPos = dragger.offsetLeft; 

    //check if dragger is within the boundaries i.e. the width of the line
    if(newPos > 0 && newPos < lineWidth){
      currentValue = Math.round(newPos / fraction); 
      dragger.style.left = (fraction * currentValue) + 'px';

      currentValue = currentValue * step; 
      currentValue += minvalue;

    } else if (newPos <= 0){

      currentValue = minvalue;  
      dragger.style.left = 0 + 'px';
      newPos = 1; 

    } else if(newPos >= lineWidth){

      currentValue = maxvalue; 
      dragger.style.left = lineWidth + 'px';
      newPos = lineWidth; 

    }

    //only call the callback and fire change event if the dragger position changes
    if(prevDraggerPos != dragger.offsetLeft){
      _fireChangeEvent();
      if(change !== null) change(currentValue);
    }

  }
}

/*
 * Function called when onmouseup/touchend event is fired  
 * @param {Object} e Event object   
 */
var _dragStop = function(e){
  if(!e){ e = window.event; }
  e.preventDefault();

  if(_isMobile.any()){
    dragger.removeEventListener('touchmove', _dragMove);
    dragger.removeEventListener('touchend', _dragStop);
  } else {
    //clear the handler functions
    dragger.onmousemove = null; 
    dragger.onmouseup = null; 

    window.onmousemove = null;
    window.onmouseup = null;
  }

  dragging = false;
  //revert to default cursor 
  document.body.style.cursor = 'default'; 
}


/**************
 PUBLIC SCOPE
***************/

/*
 * Returns the current value of slider as a percentage
 *
 * @return {float} Current slider value as a percentage
 * between 0 and 1  
 */
this.getPercentage = function getPercentage() {
   var percent = ( (fraction * (currentValue/step)) / (lineWidth / 100) ) / 100; 
   return (percent === 1 || percent === 0) ? percent : percent.toFixed(2);  
};

/*
 * Set the dragger's current value to a percentage
 *
 * @param {float} perc Percentage value to set the slider to
 */
this.setPercentage = function setPercentage(perc) {
    var p = perc * 100, 
        r = 100/range,
        v = Math.round(p / r) * step;  

    that.setValue(v);
};

/*
 * Returns the current value of the slider as an integer  
 *
 * @return {int} Current slider value
 */
this.getValue = function getValue() {
  return currentValue;
};

/*
 * Sets the current value of the slider   
 *
 * @param {int} val Value to set the slider to     
 */
this.setValue = function setValue(val) {
  dragger.style.left = (fraction * (val/step)) + 'px';
  currentValue = val; 
  currentValue += minvalue;

  //trigger change event
  _fireChangeEvent();
  if(change !== null) change(currentValue);
};

/*
* Calls the parameter function when slider's value
* has changed
*
* @param {function} f Function to call when slider's
* value changes
*/
this.onchange = function(f){
  el.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    f(currentValue);
  }, false);
} 


/**************
 INITIALISE 
***************/

_init();

  }

  // expose access to the constructor
  window.Slider = Slider;


} )( window );
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/stayko88/knxt31vx/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your configuration is just a bunch of variables:

```
var opts = opts || {},
    el = el,
    minvalue = opts.minvalue || 0,
    maxvalue = opts.maxvalue || 10,
    step = opts.step || 1,
    change = opts.change || null;
```

This makes it far more difficult to identify accesses to the options in the rest of the code. I recommend you use an object for the options, have an object that provides all the defaults for each property. When building the options object for a given instance, you copy all of the properties from the default, then copy all of the properties from the passed-in options object. Another approach is to use the defaults as a prototype for the options object, copying properties from the passed options object.

---

```
dragger.addEventListener("touchstart", _dragStart, false);
dragger.addEventListener("touchmove", _dragMove, false);
dragger.addEventListener("touchend", _dragStop, false);
```

It is generally not considered a a good idea to be frequently attaching and detaching event listeners. One small mistake and you might end up with event handlers piling up on an element, or a lifeless element, because no handler got reattached. It makes maintenance more difficult.

---

```
el.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
```

This code sets a new listener on the element every time. This is far more expensive than having an array of functions in your plugin, and one event listener for `onchange`. When someone calls `onchange`, you `.push` the function into the change callback list. When a change event fires, you call all of the functions in the change callback array.

---

```
  // expose access to the constructor
  window.Slider = Slider;
```

Before (potentially) overwriting `window.Slider`, you should copy it into a variable in your plugin called `oldSlider`. Add a `noConflict` method that puts back the value of `window.Slider` that you saved in your `oldSlider`, and returns your instance of Slider (whatever you had in `window.Slider`). This way, you can coexist with another plugin that sets `window.Slider`, that isn't written by such a considerate developer.

Comment: Nice answer. Welcome to Code Review!

Comment: RE: "It is generally not considered a a good idea to be frequently attaching and detaching event listeners" -- I disagree. When dealing with events that fire rapidly, it is a good idea to detach events when you don't want to respond to them. Having to constantly guard an event handler against events you don't want to respond to is far more expensive and difficult to maintain than simply removing the event handler.

Comment: RE: "This code sets a new listener on the element every time. This is far more expensive than having an array of functions in your plugin..." Are there any actual performance tests proving this? And if there is a difference, is it one that the user will _actually_ notice? A few millis here and there is nothing. It's only when getting around [400ms that people can actually cognitively perceive a difference](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2009/06/speed-matters.html).

Comment: @GregBurghardt [This test](http://jsperf.com/many-listeners-vs-one-listener) seems to confirm that it is faster to maintain your own array of callbacks and use one event listener. It isn't a huge difference, but it helps for extremely spammy events like `resize` and `scroll`. In many cases the difference would be negligible.

Comment: The difference is negligable at worst. Furthermore, the `onchange` event is not "spammy". Keeping an array of listeners is a premature optimization for the `onchange` event.